# How to debug a python project with shell script as the entry?

Tags: python, shell, debugging, pycharm

When I tried to debug some Deep Learning projects, I noticed that there are many projects use the shell script as the method of passing parameters. We can easily run these projects by `bash run.sh` in command line, but how to debug these kind of projects in IDEs like Pycharm?

I have tried to use some methods of python to call system commands like: `os.system('bash run.sh')` in `debugger.py` and simply debug the `debugger.py`. But the breakpoint set by pycharm in this method do not work, and will be directly ignored. What is the reason?

I also try to parse the passed parameters in the shell script and add these parameters in the debug configuration of pycharm like this:

debug configuration

[image: 1]

but it seems too troublesome, especially when the incoming parameters are complex.

Is there any elegant solution to debug a python project with shell script as the entry?
Or is it not normative to write too complex parameter processing flow in shell script?

Comment: This is not a strict programming question, but about how to use programming tools. Assuming that you Python main program doesn't do much more than collecting the programming arguments and call some method with them, I would debug just this "principal" methods and not care much about the shell script wrapper.

Comment: Having the parameters preprocessed in a shell script, is not necessary, but comes handy at times. I do this often too. But if you want to do **everything** inside Python, you are free not to use a shell interface at all.

Comment: The Python debugger obviously won't be able to debug shell scripts. A common debugging technique is to run the script with `bash -x` to get debugging output from the shell itself. You'll need to figure out how to read it, but it's not terribly hard. Perhaps also investigate the shell's `-v` option.

Comment: @user1934428, I don't know why you mention that this is a question about how to use programming tools. I assume the OP know what they ask. In case you're the one voted to close as off-topic, please realize that _questions about software tools primarily used by programmers_ are explicitly **on-topic** on Stack Overflow. Having said that, I think the question can be improved somewhat, but generally seems okay to me.

Comment: @wovano : I didn't see a programming problem here. It is a question about debugging a system consisting of shell script and Python code as a whole, and while I don't know whether such a combined debugging tool exists, I think the OP is better served here on [su]. One could alternatively argue that the question asks for a **opinion** on or a **recommendation** for a debugging tool, but this would be off-topic as well.

Comment: @user1934428, I think the question is pretty unclear, but how I understand it, is that OP is trying to debug a Python script that process command-line arguments, and is struggling with how to launch the debugger while providing the correct arguments. When using a wrapper script, the debugger does not debug the main script but the wrapper script instead, and manually configuring the IDE is cumbersome. If this is what OP is asking, then it certainly is a programming question and seems better suited here than on Super User IMHO.

Comment: NB: Indeed it could arguably considered opinion-based, but that depends of the fact if a good solution exists or not. If a solution exists it can be answered with facts, if not, it could be answered with (opinion-based) work-arounds. But this is hard to say in advance.

Comment: @wovano: You convinced me .....